# Panel data analysis

Tags: regression, panel-data

`GEE` is one of the models that used in panel data, one example is

```
library(glmgee)
data(depression)
glmgee('depressd ~ visit + group', id=subj, family=binomial("logit"), data = depression)
```

Typically within a cluster the correlation structure is specified by the parameter `corstr`

However what about correlation between clusters? Are clusters assumed to be independent in `GEE`?